# Receive Talk Detect events From Receiving channels in asterisk?

Tags: asterisk

Let me explain my scenario first, what i am trying is to detect channel talking and silence events during call, and perform some task on event detection, i have successfully detect 'talk_detect' events on the channel who initiated the call but i am not able to detect the 'talk_detect' events on the channel who receives the call, here is a code sample:

Dailing channel:

```
exten =111,1,Answer()
exten =111,n,Set(SPYGROUP=3300)
exten =111,n,Set(DENOISE(rx)=on)
exten =111,n,Set(TALK_DETECT(set)=1000)
exten =111,n,Dail(SIP/111,100)
exten =111,n,Hangup()
```

Receiving channel:

```
exten =222,1,Answer()
exten =222,n,Set(SPYGROUP=3300)
exten =222,n,Set(DENOISE(rx)=on)
exten =222,n,Set(TALK_DETECT(set)=1000)
exten =222,n,Dail(SIP/222,100)
exten =222,n,Hangup()
```

but it only enables the talk_detect events on dailing channel please guide how can i detect talk events on both channel.

Comment: This one is duplicate. You already asked same question few month before. Please re-read answer on that page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asterisk playback sound file into ConfBridge?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359445/asterisk-playback-sound-file-into-confbridge)

Comment: @arheops thanks to you for replying, the question you referred me is playbacksound in confbridge etc, and my question over here is totally different, sorry but i shall not take this point positively that my question is possibly duplicate, someone asked you in comments about this and tell me how can i reach that? and frankly speaking after reading that i am still not able to solve my problem with the solution you have suggested, instead of writing this that my question is duplicate you can help me on this with proper answer if you know how to do it. please do not mind, and try to help me.

Comment: if you know how to solve it then please post your solution in answers, that will be great and i shall be very thankful to you if you'll do that...

Answer (score 0):

Answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556653/asterisk-silence-detection-on-connected-call) describes exactly how to do it.  They key is that you need to dial with b parameter (doesn't seem to be documented).   b parameter is where you specify pre-dial code that triggers the other channel's talk detection